# Same file can not be run on another computer for flowchart code

Tags: flow-charts

I add following code at the beginning to draw some flowcharts. But it's very strange that the tex file can be run at one computer but cann't be run on another computer. There is a error `enter file name:`. Could any one know why?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,calrsfs}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{epsfig,epsf,epic}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{extarrows}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%for flowchart
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,calc,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    process/.style={
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=1.6cm,
        text centered,
        },
    process1/.style={
        text width=2.5cm, draw,
        minimum height=0.8cm,
        text centered,
        },
    description/.style={
        text centered,
        text width=10cm,
    },
    myarrow/.style={
        postaction={
            decorate, decoration={
                markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{Stealth};
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\singlespacing}



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Note}
\newtheorem{hint}[theorem]{Hint}





\newcommand{\st}{\textrm{s.t}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\emph{d}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\emph{Var}}
\newcommand{\nty}{n\rightarrow\infty}
\newcommand{\tr}{\textrm{\textbf{tr}}}
\newcommand{\BM}{Brownian motion}
\newcommand{\dt}{\textrm{d}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\EH}{\widehat{\mathbb{E}}}
\newcommand{\II}{\mathbb{I}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\ITO}{It\^{o} integral}
\newcommand{\limn}{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}}
\newcommand{\intt}{\int_0^t}
\newcommand{\ip}{It\^{o} process}
\newcommand{\dr}{\textrm{d}}
\newcommand{\PS}{\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}}
\newcommand{\ES}{\widetilde{\mathbb{E}}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\WS}{\widetilde{W}}
\newcommand{\WH}{\widehat{W}}
\newcommand{\MH}{\widehat{M}}
\newcommand{\eTt}{e^{-r(T-t)}}
\newcommand{\fa}{\textrm{for all}}
\newcommand{\vlx}{v_{L_*}(x)}
\newcommand{\tls}{\tau_{L_*}}
\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}
\newcommand{\pap}{perpetual American put}
\newcommand{\vl}{\pmb |}
\newcommand{\num}{num\'{e}raire}
\newcommand{\fors}{\textrm{For}_S(t,T)}
\newcommand{\btau}{\bar{\tau}}
\newcommand{\Btt}{B(t,T)}
\newcommand{\et}{e^{-\lambda t}}
\newcommand{\ert}{e^{-rt}}
\newcommand{\ol}{\dfrac{1}{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\pp}{Possion process}
\newcommand{\kk}{k=0,1,\ldots}
\newcommand{\var}{\textrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\Nt}{$N(t)$ be a \pp\ with intensity $\lambda>0$}
\newcommand{\cpp}{compound Poisson process}
\newcommand{\sumN}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N(t)}}
\newcommand{\stime}{0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n}
\newcommand{\mgf}{moment-generating function}
\newcommand{\rc}{right-continuous}
\newcommand{\lc}{left-continuous}
\newcommand{\sumst}{\sum\limits_{0<s\leq t}}
\newcommand{\ls}{\widetilde{\lambda}}
\newcommand{\MS}{\widetilde{M}}
\newcommand{\ps}{\widetilde{p}}
\newcommand{\fs}{\widetilde{f}}
\newcommand{\N}{\textbf{\textrm{N}}}
\newcommand{\imvol}{\sigma_{\textrm{imp}}}

\begin{document}{\allowdisplaybreaks[4]}




\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Par Asset Swap}\label{asset swap}
At initiation there is a cash flow $100-P$(seller). The exchanges take place regardless of whether the bond defaults.

At initiation Asset Swap buyer purchases bond worth full price $P$ in return for par
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Default\\ protection\\ seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Default\\ protection\\ buyer};

    %\draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=8ex, xshift=-7ex]p1.east) -- node[description, above] {90 basis points per year} ([yshift=8ex, xshift=7ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth, line width=1pt] ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=8ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {100} ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=-8ex]p1.east);
    \draw [-Stealth, line width=1pt]([yshift= 8ex,xshift=-0.7ex]$(p1)$) --node[midway] (Rect){}([yshift=8ex,xshift=-0.7ex]$(p2)$);
    \draw[fill=white] ($(Rect)+(-1.5,-0.7)$)rectangle($(Rect)+(1.5,0.7)$) node[midway] (Text){};
    \node at (Text) {\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering
             Bond\\ worth P
          \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
and enters into an interest rate swap paying a fixed coupon of $C$ in return for LIBOR plus asset swap spread $S$
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};
    \node[process1, right=3em of p2]  (p3) {Bond};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {C} ([yshift=2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, below] {LIBOR + S} ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] (p3.west) -- node[description, below] {C} (p2.east);
    \draw[dashed] ($(p1)+(-1.8,-1)$)rectangle($(p2)+(1.8,1)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
If default occurs the asset swap buyer loses the coupon and principal redemption on the bond, \emph{so the spread $S$ is compensation for the default of bond}. The interest rate swap will continue until bond maturity or can be closed out at market value.
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};
    \node[process1, right=3em of p2]  (p3) {Bond};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {C} ([yshift=2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, below] {LIBOR + S} ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] (p3.west) -- node[description, below] {C} (p2.east);
    \draw[dashed] ($(p1)+(-1.8,-1)$)rectangle($(p2)+(1.8,1)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)+(-1.7,-0.8)$)--($(p3)+(1.7,0.8)$);
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(p3)+(-1.7,0.8)$)--($(p3)+(1.7,-0.8)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\item \textbf{Market Asset Swap}
At the beginning, there is no cash flow, but at the maturity, there is an exchange of par for the original price of the bond $100-P$(seller). The notional of the LIBOR leg(seller) is then scaled by the full price $P.$
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Default\\ protection\\ seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Default\\ protection\\ buyer};

    %\draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=8ex, xshift=-7ex]p1.east) -- node[description, above] {90 basis points per year} ([yshift=8ex, xshift=7ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth, line width=1pt] ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=8ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {P} ([yshift=-8ex, xshift=-8ex]p1.east);
    \draw [-Stealth, line width=1pt]([yshift= 8ex,xshift=-0.7ex]$(p1)$) --node[midway] (Rect){}([yshift=8ex,xshift=-0.7ex]$(p2)$);
    \draw[fill=white] ($(Rect)+(-1.5,-0.7)$)rectangle($(Rect)+(1.5,0.7)$) node[midway] (Text){};
    \node at (Text) {\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering
             Bond\\ worth P
          \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};
    \node[process1, right=3em of p2]  (p3) {Bond};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {C} ([yshift=2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, below] {Libor + S on notional P} ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] (p3.west) -- node[description, below] {C} (p2.east);
    \draw[dashed] ($(p1)+(-1.8,-1)$)rectangle($(p2)+(1.8,1)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
At maturity there is an exchange of
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Asset Swap\\ Seller};
    \node[process, right=12em of p1]  (p2) {Asset Swap\\ Buyer};

    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, above] {100} ([yshift=2ex]p1.east);
    \draw[-Stealth] ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, below] {P} ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\emph{The final swap just gives back return. In the Par asset swap since bond = 100 at final, there is no cash flow. }

\item \textbf{CDS(Credit Default Swap)}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[process] (p1) {Default\\ protection\\ buyer};
    \node[process, right=16em of p1]  (p2) {Default\\ protection\\ seller};

    \draw[myarrow=.9] ([yshift=2ex]p1.east) -- node[description, above] {90 basis points per year} ([yshift=2ex]p2.west);
    \draw[myarrow=.9] ([yshift=-2ex]p2.west) -- node[description, below] {Payment if default by\\ reference entity} ([yshift=-2ex]p1.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you complete your code? In the actual version it stops in the middle of a command.

Comment: Are you sure both PCs have the same files installed? For example is one of them running MikTeX, which is known to not install everything by default

Comment: You've only reported part of the error, look in the `.log` file and you'll see which specific file was not found.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have added the complete code, do you know what's the problem?

Comment: `arrows.meta` was introduced with version 3 of `pgf`/TikZ, the computer where it doesn't work probably has version 2.x. (You can check the version with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \pgfversion \end{document}`.) Upgrade, or don't use `arrows.meta`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It shows 2.10, so I just download  a version 3?

Comment: Depends on what TeX distribution you have installed. If you have MikTeX the use the [Update manager](https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex) to upgrade the package. If you're using TeX Live or MacTeX then I would at least consider upgrading to the 2017 version.